# initial background-size before css3

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaCHP/)**

Before css3 it was not possible to resize background image. After applying background-size in css3 we are able to resize background image. So I'm confused with my background (I think it should be 100% background-size initially before and after of css3). So why my background-image is not showing fully, at right side it is cutting the image.

It should be like this

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

But working like this

```
+----------------------
|
+----------------------
```

> When I apply background-size: 100%; it works perfect.

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: when background-size is not applied, the size of the image must be bigger than space available to the image. Can you check ?

Comment: What is initial size of background-image?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background

Comment: Without applying background-size: 100%, Can I achieve full image?

Comment: Your image would have to be as wide/tall as the browser window or larger. You can also use JavaScript to achieve the same effect, even if your image is not the ideal size to begin with.